# Xampp setup with multihost - cannot open page because it says it wants to use HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, hsts

I am using xampp and created a multihost setup. When I open my page it says it wants to use HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) and cannot use the page.

How can I disable that it wants to use https for opening the page?

Comment: Did you search for that problem in the context of your browser? Your browser has been instructed to always use https for that domain - if you deliberately want to override it (until the next time it's instructed): That's a browser configuration, and off topic here (see [help/on-topic]).

Comment: I tried different browsers. Also in the browser the https only mode is deactivated.